# cucumber show me the page not showing page (Solution: it was on the wrong line)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Adding the line "Then show me the page" to a cucumber scenario works on my colleague's computer with the same setup, but not on mine. In fact, adding in a pause step definition and calling it seems to be completely ignored.

Step definitions:

```
Then /^show me the page$/ do
  save_and_open_page
end

AfterStep('@pause') do
  print "Press Return to continue"
  STDIN.getc
end
```

feature:

```
(line 25) Scenario Outline: An authorised user visits the blah..,
Given a blah: ... blah ...
  And I am logged in as <role>
  And the date is 1 April 2012
When I go to the blah page
 And I click "foobar"
Then I should see "Blah foobar"
And I should see "Foobar on Mon Apr 1 00:00:00 2012 by <email>"
Then show me the page
And ...
```

Command line:

```
cucumber features/blah/foos.feature:25 --require features --tags @pause
```

Using Firefox 16.02 (Avoiding the bugs in 17)

Both machines have git-fetch'd, pull'd, bundle install'd so all gems are identical, both using Rbenv versions * 1.9.3-p327-perf. I may be missing something obvious...

Update: tmp/capybara/ does not contain the file, so it isn't being saved now...

Solution thanks to Beerlington: Move the show me the page line up one. There was failure before show me the page, thus it did not get shown.

Comment: @pause credit to http://bjeanes.com/2010/09/pausing-cucumber-scenarios-to-debug

Comment: Is it actually getting to that step or is it failing before it gets there?

Comment: Oh no... that was it 0_0 DERP \*kickself\* Put as answer? I should have moved "show me the page" up one line, I typed it one line higher on colleagues computer. Maybe that's why the pause thing wasn't working either...

Comment: Eh, I don't know how much value this would have for future visitors. I'd be tempted just to close it.

Comment: Closing would be best, but in lieu of that, having an answer entered is much more courteous -- otherwise this question remains forever in the "Unanswered" filter.

Comment: @Beerlington - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn it's all yours, but thanks for the mention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Solution thanks to [Beerlington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167614/beerlington): Move the show me the page line up one. There was failure before show me the page, thus it did not get shown.